# Is it possible to train a FindObject and mark the object?

Tags: machine-learning

We can use `Classify` to train a classifier to classify an object.
Can we make the classify more intelligent or work like `FindFaces`.

In `FindFaces`, we can mark a face(with an frame) in an image. 
So can we make my `FindObject` function be able to mark the Object?

I find a binary classifier is able to identity an object in a large image, if we can mark the position of the object, then I can crop the object, and add it into future train set.

Comment: There is a face detection example under Applications in ImageCorrelate: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCorrelate.html

Comment: This task is called object detection in computer vision. The traditional way to do is using a sliding window + classifier to find the locations of the objects. The classifier can be a HOG(histogram of oriented gradients), convolutional neural network, etc. Recently, there are technics map directly from the image to object localtions, such as YOLO, SSD etc., which should be able to be build using the current neural network framework in Mathematica.