# How to write a RCNN (region-cnn)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision

Has anyone end-to-end trained a single net that can **find the location of objects in an image** (with v11.1)? Here's an [example](https://github.com/rbgirshick/rcnn) of a region-cnn in action, and [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.2524.pdf) is a good description of the approach.

Comment: related to question about [finding objects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139534/is-it-possible-to-train-a-findobject-and-mark-the-object)

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but I think the newly introduced spatial transformer layer can be used to conduct roi pooling, with 0 as the inputs to the skew x and y parameters. I can't think of any other way to do the roi pooling step within Mathematica at the moment, but I haven't fully explored all the new layers yet either.